# How can I create a commit with a new SHA in git?

Tags: git, commit, gnupg, sha

I need to create an equivalent commit object with a different SHA in Git. All commits are GPG signed. I know that I can change author + commit timestamps, but the resolution is only a second, and we are not permitted to deviate from the system clock by more than a second. I also cannot change commit messages, author / commiter names and emails and / or the key used to sign the commit. Which other fields of the commit can I change in order to get a different commit message?

---

Motivation: We are using an internal tool which for some reason does not work if two properties reference the same commit, even though we are setting it intentionally.

Comment: Time zone offset?

Comment: [This gist](https://gist.github.com/masak/2415865) has pretty much all the details about what goes into a commit id.

Comment: Seems like it would be easier to change the internal tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technical answer to the question is this:

The hashed data includes:

- a header you don't control (and that is, in any case, derived from the other data I'm about to mention)
- the commit's `TREE` object hash - a reflection of the commit content
- the parent `COMMIT` object(s) hash(es)
- Author name,email,timestamp
- Committer name,email,timestamp
- Commit message

Varying the `TREE` may stretch the definition of "equivalent" commit.  You've explicitly ruled out changing the commit message or author / committer info.  The remaining option is the commit parent list, but whether that makes any sense to talk about depends on what it is you're doing.

So since options are limited, let's take a quick look at each of these (even the ones that seem to be excluded):

**`TREE` object**: This uniquely represents the content - i.e. what data you would see in what files at what paths in the working tree.  At a glance, this seems like the thing that must be unchanged to meet the most basic definition of "equivalent commit".  Of course, any change - no matter how small, no matter where in the work tree - would change the hash, so maybe you could wedge in a file or directory specifically for nonce values to vary the hash?

**Author or committer Info**: First thing to think about: How sensitive is the requirement not to touch names?  Could you stick an invisible character at the end of the name and be ok, or do they have to match bit-for-bit?

Alternately, those time stamps... Saying you can't vary from the system clock, when the commit timestamp is defined to refer to commit creation time anyway, seems pedantic unless you're trying to create several equivalent commits all at once.  Even if you need two at the same time, you should be able to do that without exceeding your tolerance.

**Commit Message**: Again, how strict is the requirement not to change this?  Could you get by with a newline, or at least an invisible character?

**Parent Commit**: If you're still at brick walls with all of the above, then here's what's left.  And this really boils down to, what are the commits *for*?  Is the duplicate commit going to have the same parent?

```
P -- A
 \
  A'
```

In that case you can't really do anything here.  But alternately, if it's parallel trees of commits:

```
P -- A

P' -- A'
```

Well, then all you need to do is seed each tree with a root commit that differs in some way.  Commit messages like "Root commit 1", "Root commit 2", ..., for example?

Comment: Where is the signature stored?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the signature is stored in the git database with the object it signs. This could be in a loose object (`.git/objects/01/23456789012345678901234567890123456789`) or it could be in a pack file (1.git/objects/pack/...`)